# How to remove file permissions on linux from an external hard drive?

Tags: linux, macos, file, permissions, hard-drive

My macbook recently died and I am currently trying to figure out how to copy my data.

What I did was, I took out the hard drive, put it in an enclosure and plugged it in to my other laptop that runs linux.

The problem is, I cannot copy files from the hard drive due to file permissions. I tried to access the hard drive as root. But I still cannot copy files.

How do I remove file permissions from the harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

To make the partition accessible under Linux run:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/<drive-name>/
```

this should make the mac drive accessible for you.

*Changing ownership would do about the same, but you need not worry about it.*

Comment: the drive path is dev/sdc2. But it says it's not a directory.
I typed: sudo chmod -R 777 /dev/sdc2

Comment: files listed in the /dev directory are devices. i meant that you should change the permissions on the path where that drive is mounted. it should be under /media/<drive-name>. i've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I tried this command as well as `sudo chown -R root:root /media/<drive-name>/ `, but I am getting this error for each file: `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/media/<drive-name>/path/to/file’: Read-only file system`. The drive is coming off a Mac OSX system. Any suggestions?